# Unable to run nodeJS App on A2 Hosting shared plan

Tags: node.js, deployment, hosting, shared-hosting

I'm trying to run the simplest node/express app which has a single get request that sends hello world as response. Works on local.

I followed this tutorial for deploying it on A2 hosting shared plan, but I'm getting default a2 hosting page and not my app.

Tutorial followed: https://medium.com/@pampas93/host-your-node-js-app-on-shared-hosting-go-beyond-localhost-73ab923e6691

I tried contacting support. They responded:
App is on a different location and website is looking at different location.
To make it use the path that you need may require custom coding or alterations to the .htaccess file to change the document root for the primary domain.

I'm not able to understand what changes to make/how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

The .htaccess file in my cpanel is empty right now. No code is written inside it.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also trying to run a javaScript which has a relative address in it which runs on local and not when the app is deployed. This makes sense that the App is on different location and website is looking at different location but I am still not successful in figuring out what is the correct location.

Comment: No, A2 customer support was not able to help me in this issue. So, I had to apply for refund and shift to another hosting provider. Its called Namecheap. It also supports node apps on shared hosting.

Comment: Ok. So I figured it that the files need to set the permission to execute in order to access them.

Comment: I have been hosting on A2's shared plan for a while, products that consist of Angular on the front-end + API implemented with ExpressJS and NodeJS. Everything just works, flawlessly. Not sure if it changed since this question was asked. Great hosting, b.t.w.